# Problems when I try to switch java to be used as the default

Tags: java, linux

Hello everybody my problem is simple I guess, I am using kali linux fresh install and while i am trying to install Java, according to this guide:

http://www.blackmoreops.com/2013/10/26/how-to-install-java-jdk-in-kali-linux/

Terminal throw me this error:

> update-alternatives: error: alternative path /opt/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java doesn't exist

Thank you very much for any comments.

Answer (score 0):

The link clearly shows it set the path as

```
update-alternatives --set java /opt/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java
```

Installer is expecting the java installation files to be at path ----> /opt/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java

Comment: Excuse but I am not an expert. Even I do not understand what to change in the command I just follow the steps obviously I have to change the path but I don't know the **order** in the command. Well to be honest I don't in what part I have to change the path. But thank you for your comment I'll figure out.